# The output of the following code is unexpected:

Tags: verilog

I am trying to display time. But it returns the value 0. What's wrong?

CODE:

```
module hello_world;
integer in_reg;
initial
begin
  in_reg = 3'd2;
  $monitor($time, " In register value = %b\n",in_reg[2:0]);
end
endmodule
```

OUTPUT:

> 0 In register value = 010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. When the `$monitor` statement outputs its line, simulation time is 0.

As I guess you know, `$monitor` outputs a line whenever any of its inputs changes. It *does not* do this for $time, however, because it makes little sense to do so. (When would it output a line? Every ns? Every ps? Every fs?)

So, your code sets `in_reg` to `3'd2` and then `$monitor` displays that. Then the simulation finishes. Nothing else happens.

Comment: The output remains 0 when I replace $time with $display. 
I have just began to get going with verilog so trying a lot of stuff. FYI, this was a problem statement in the book I refer to!

Comment: The output will be 0 with `$display`. In that case, the `$display` statement is executed at time 0, so 0 is what is output by the `$time` _system function_. No time is consumed by your simulation (because there are no delays in your code), so your simulation finishes at time 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the below code will print in_reg contents 10 times every 10ns, the simulation time would be displayed as 10,20,...etc

```
`timecale 1ns/1ps
module hello_world;
integer in_reg;  
initial
begin
  in_reg = 3'd2;
 repeat(10)
 begin
  #10;
  $display($time, " In register value = %b\n",in_reg); 
 end
end
endmodule
```